# BootStrap 4 - Make Text/Icon Flush ( bottom align) With Row

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Referring to the screenshot  Below ( lines red / blue  are from pesticide - a firefox addonn );

[image]

Code for the above;

```
<div class="row my-auto">
     <p class="h6">
        <span class="pl-3 text-white  align-bottom"><i class="icofont-business-man  "></i>Particulars - Add Particulars Below</span>
         <span class="align-bottom"></span>
     </p>   
</div>
```

HI, I am trying to get the text  flush to the bottom of the row (blue line ) from the currnt red line. The aim is to make the text flush with the bottom of the row like the icon.

I have tried bootsrap classes like my-auto , mb-0, align-*, no-gutter  but to no avail.

Any pointers ?

Answer (score 0):

My personal preference is to use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) for this kind of alignment. I am no bootstrap expert, but you should be able to do it with some classes like so.

```
<div class="row my-auto">
     <p class="h6 d-flex align-items-baseline">
        <span class="pl-3 text-white  align-bottom"><i class="icofont-business-man  "></i>Particulars - Add Particulars Below</span>
         <span class="align-bottom"></span>
     </p>   
</div>
```

Using CSS instead, it would be:

```
.h6 {
    display: flex;
    align-items: baseline;
}
```

Comment: Chris ->  I tried both methods u mentioned above but the text and icon seem flush to the top of the row... Do i have to do a 1 row table to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
<div class="row my-auto d-flex align-items-end">
   <p class="h6">
      <span class="pl-3 text-white  align-bottom"><i class="icofont-business-man  "></i>Particulars - Add Particulars Below</span>
      <span class="align-bottom"></span>
   </p>   
</div>
```

Comment: Hi ...I tried  "d-flex align-items-end" in the div tag. NO. Tried it in p tag. NO. Treid in both div tag and p tag. NO. The text is still flush to the tope of the row. Do i have to do a 1 row table  to get this aligned properly ?

Comment: Rupesh -> your logic seems right -> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/flex/#align-items . Just cant seem to work here ? Is this an icofont problem ?

Comment: try removing `<span class="align-bottom"></span>` from your `p` tag.

Comment: Rupesh - I removed align-bottom as per your suggestion. Same problem. It just seems stuck to the top of the row ? Do i have to make a 1 row table to get this aligned to the bottom perfectly ?

Comment: You can use a table, but ideally, flexbox would have solved your problem perfectly.

Comment: Rupesh -> Anything else i can do  to get this flexbox thing working ? I was kinda surprised i couldnt get it to work

Comment: Try removing all and starting all again just with flexbox and this keep the text out of span element.